# How many accounts of the Battle of Red Mountain are there?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

So, I've been wandering around Morrowind collecting accounts of the key event of the game's backstory.  I'm up to eight mutually-conflicting versions (the official Temple version, the Temple Apographa version, two versions from Vivec, two Ashlander versions, the Telvanni version, and a Nord version), plus a fragmentary version from Dagoth Ur.

Are there any accounts of the battle I've missed?  I'm down to two facts that all the accounts agree on: that the Chimer/Dunmer and the Dwemer were present at the battle, and that the Dwemer didn't win.  A version that contradicts one or both of these facts would be ideal.

Comment: This is why i never read any of the books in Morrowind.

Comment: @Nelson Then you dunno what you missed. There are rather entertaining short stories in many of them.

Comment: It isn't completely sure if Dwemer disappearance counts as not winning,.There's slim chance they didn't really disintegrated themselves, just "ascended".

Answer (score 3):

The core of the answer is "Nobody really knows what happened at Red Mountain"

From the [UESP article](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Battle_of_Red_Mountain) for the battle:

> In a [2005 interview](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/General:Douglas_Goodall_Interview), Douglas Goodall stated that during the development of Morrowind there was no "official" account of what happened at the Battle of Red Mountain. "...When I was at Bethesda, there was officially no answer. No one knew what really happened...."

You are correct in noticing the discrepancies between accounts of the battle. You summarized what most sources agree on: The Chimer fought the Dwemer, and the Dwemer disappeared. That's about the only thing everybody agrees on.

There are four main accounts of the battle:  Vivec's story, The Ashland version, The Outlander version, and and Dagoth'Urs letter. There are additional supplementary sources, but these four are the main interpretations of the Battle.

Comment: Actually, we can't confirm that the Chimer fought the Dwemer: the Nord account (*Five Songs of King Wulfharth*) says it was Chimer and Dwemer allied against the Nords.

Comment: Updated. "What we can confirm -> "most sources agree on"